Unable to connect to Windows share from Linux Mint
I'm running Linux Mint and trying to connect to a Windows 10 share. I'm using the network connection. I can connect to the machine but I can't open any of the folders. I get a popup that authentication is required. I enter the user name either as name or machine\name along with password and it fails each time.
I'm not sure what else to do.

Have you tried this? https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/su22oj/comment/j4pikdz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

How are the shares configured in Windows? What versions of Windows and Linux are you running? What folder(s) are being shared? Are other devices able to access these Windows shares OK without entering credentials? Please add this and any other information you feel will help us understand your situation to the main post using the EDIT button.
